# richfaces 3.3.3 on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to run Richfaces 3.3.3Final with Google app engine but richfaces uses javax.imageio.ImageIO restricted class.

Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed [known](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1268). However, at the last [JavaOne](http://relation.to/Bloggers/RichFacesAtJavaOne2010) JBoss presented [RichFaces in the Cloud](http://www.slideshare.net/balunasj/rich-faces-inthecloudminibooth) where JBoss introduced [RichFaces 4.0 with GAE archetype](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/trunk/archetypes/rf-gae-sample/) (for Maven2).